# Prove Inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the inequality 
$$\left(\frac{\sum_j (x_j+y_j)^p}{\sum_j (x_j+y_j)^r}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-r}} \le \left(\frac{\sum_j x_j^p}{\sum_j x_j^r}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-r}} +      \left(\frac{\sum_j y_j^p}{\sum_j y_j^r}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-r}}$$
where $x_j$ and $y_j$ are positive, $0 \lt r \le 1 \le p$

using Holder's Inequality can  simplify this inequality a little bit since $\left( \sum_j x_j^p\right)^{1/p}$ is the supremum of all $\sum_j x_jz_j$ for $z_j \ge 0$ and $\sum_j z_j^q = 1$ ($\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p} =1$), hence we can rewrite the righthand side of this inequality as $$\left(\frac{\left( \sum_j x_jz_j \right)^p}{\sum_j x_j^r}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-r}} + \left(\frac{\left(\sum_j y_j \hat z_j \right)^p}{\sum_j y_j^r}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-r}} $$

but i was stuck here, is there anyone who knows how to prove this?

is there any advice for handling inequalities?